# Is it possible to prove that projectiles with drag will not travel in a parabola under the theory of classical mechanics?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag

Can you prove that projectiles will travel in a parabola, provided the acceleration due to gravity $g$ does not vary significantly along the trajectory? This should take air resistance into account. I know how to prove a parabolic trajectory without air resistance (see [my user page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User%3aFuse809#Proof_that_a_projectile_will_travel_in_a_parabola), for instance, where I have successfully proven this), but with air resistance, the equations get more complicated and difficult to solve analytically.

Comment: Comment to the question (v3): Generically, the trajectory of a projectile with drag is _not_ a parabola. Suggestion: Change title to the opposite statement.

Comment: Also, if you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: Done, sorry for the mix up.

Comment: Yes you can. In the x-direction equation you need to consider the deceleration due to drag ($\sim v_x^2$). You would also need to consider deceleration due to drag in the y direction, which will be $\sim v_y^2$, but the constants of proportionality for the two might not be equal.

Answer (score 4):

Take the equations of motion and plug in a generic parabola. It should be easy to prove that no constant coefficients of the parabola satisfy the equations of motion.

From $  \vec{a} =  \vec{g} - \beta |\vec{v}|^2 \frac{\vec{v}}{|\vec{v}|} $ by component

$$ \begin{pmatrix} \ddot{x} \\ \ddot{y} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -g \end{pmatrix}   - \beta \sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2} \begin{pmatrix} \dot{x} \\ \dot{y} \end{pmatrix} $$

A general parabola has properties $$ \begin{pmatrix} x(t) = x_0 + v_x t \\ y(t)=y_0+v_y t - \frac{1}{2} g t^2 \end{pmatrix} $$

and when combined with the equations of motion give

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -g \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -g \end{pmatrix}   - \beta \sqrt{v_x^2+(v_y-g t)^2} \begin{pmatrix} v_x \\ v_y-g t \end{pmatrix} $$

which can *only* be true if $\beta=0$, implying that there is no air resistance.

Comment: "which can only be true iff β=0, or with no air resistance." -> Setting $\beta=0$ already implies that there is no air resistance, since $\beta$ is the parameter for the "strength" of the resistance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can prove that it is not a parabola. For example, see the graphics at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile#Trajectory_of_a_projectile_with_air_resistance).

To solve the differential equation yourself, i think the starting point would be the equation

$m\cdot \vec{a} = -k\cdot \vec{v}^2 \vec{e}_{v} - m\cdot \vec{g}$

where a is acceleration, v the speed, k some constant defining the air resistance, m the mass of your particle and g the acceleration due Earth's gravity.

Answer (score 0):

Just solve the motion equation numerically for some set of parameters and show that those parameters do not yield a parabola. That should suffice.

Comment: That would certainly show it but that's not a proof.

Comment: Why isn't that a proof?

Comment: Well it depends on whether you want to prove they're *never* a parabola or they're *always* a parabola.  A single counter example falsifies always but doesn't falsify never.  The original author didn't specify but my reading of the question suggests that a single counter example is not what they were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Consider the parametric representation of a parabola, x = t, y = -t^2 (for a falling object). In the presence of drag, after a suitably long interval the equation for the object is x = C1, y = -C2 - C3 t (vertical linear motion at the terminal velocity of the object). The two equations are fundamentally different. The second is not a parabola.